# Can't figure out why this IEnumerable is giving this answer

Tags: c#, ienumerable

The answer to the following code is **5**

Can someone explain why this is? If you were to replace `int d1 = x.Current` with `d1 = x.Current` and declare `d1` above the while loop, the answer would be **2** and I understand why that is but I don't know why it's 5 otherwise.

```
IEnumerable<int> num = new []{10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
IEnumerable<int> div = new [] {2,3,5};

var lazy = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
var x = div.GetEnumerator();

while(x.MoveNext()){
    int d1 = x.Current;
    lazy = lazy.Concat(num.Where(s=>s % d1 == 0));
}

int count = lazy.Distinct().Count();
Console.WriteLine("{0}",count);
```

EDIT: Here is the snippet that gives you an answer of 2.

```
IEnumerable<int> num = new []{10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
IEnumerable<int> div = new [] {2,3,5};

var lazy = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
var x = div.GetEnumerator();
int d1;

while(x.MoveNext()){
    d1 = x.Current;
    lazy = lazy.Concat(num.Where(s=>s % d1 == 0));
}

int count = lazy.Distinct().Count();
Console.WriteLine("{0}",count);
```

Comment: Can you post both snippets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Peter beat me to the punch, but I was half done when his answer appeared, so I'll post it anyhow.)

You can get more insight into the difference by instrumenting the code. The instrumentation *within the lambda expression* is the thing that provides the crucial insight:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Baseline.");
        Test1();
        Console.WriteLine("Modified.");
        Test2();
    }

    static void Test1()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> num = new[] { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
        IEnumerable<int> div = new[] { 2, 3, 5 };

        var lazy = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        var x = div.GetEnumerator();

        while (x.MoveNext())
        {
            int d1 = x.Current;
            Console.WriteLine("d1 = " + d1);
            lazy = lazy.Concat(num.Where(s => {bool result = s % d1 == 0; Console.WriteLine("s = " + s + ", d1 = " + d1); return result;}));
            Console.WriteLine("lazy has " + lazy.Count());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Evaluating lazy.Distinct().Count()");        
        int count = lazy.Distinct().Count();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
    }

    static void Test2()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> num = new[] { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
        IEnumerable<int> div = new[] { 2, 3, 5 };

        var lazy = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        var x = div.GetEnumerator();
        int d1;

        while (x.MoveNext())
        {
            d1 = x.Current;
            Console.WriteLine("d1 = " + d1); 
            lazy = lazy.Concat(num.Where(s => {bool result = s % d1 == 0; Console.WriteLine("s = " + s + ", d1 = " + d1); return result;}));
            Console.WriteLine("lazy has " + lazy.Count());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Evaluating lazy.Distinct().Count()");
        int count = lazy.Distinct().Count();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
    }
}
```

After "Evaluating lazy.Distinct().Count()" is printed, you'll notice two things that might surprise you.

First, that evaluation requires re-running the lambda expression that was declared within the loop. It is easy, but wrong, to think of "lazy" as a collection of integers. In fact it is a function for creating a collection of integers, so counting the distinct elements requires re-running that function.

Second, you'll notice that the values of d1 are different between the two evaluations. In the first case, d1 is 2, and in the second case d1 is 5. The reason for this is, as Peter Duniho pointed out, that declaring d1 outside the loop allows it to retain the value that it had when the loop finished (so you have 5, the last value in the div sequence), wherease declaring it within the loop requires re-computing it (so you have 2, the first element in the div sequence).

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of the deferred execution of the lambda expression in `lazy.Concat(num.Where(s=>s % d1 == 0))`.

When you declare the variable inside the loop, each instance of the anonymous method gets its own variable. But when you declare the variable outside the loop, they all share the same variable, and of course that variable's value has just one value (the final value assigned in the loop) when the lambda expression is finally executed here:

```
int count = lazy.Distinct().Count();
```

The moral of the story: beware use of captured variables. They are often hard to reason about, so they should be used carefully.

Comment: As i understand the value 5 is only considered in the second snippet, since global variable keeps getting replaced and it considers the final value of 5, vis-a-vis local variable, which is different for each iteration and is used as is during lazy execution of the first snippet

Comment: Your understanding is correct. In the first example, a whole new variable is created for each loop iteration, so each concatenated sequence (complete with lambda expression) gets its own private copy of the iterated value.